# Put variables in one

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have this variables in javascript.

```
var overlay = $('.footer .overlay'),
    container = $('.footer .wrapper');
```

How can i put this variables in one variable?

Comment: Explain clearly wt you need!!!

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. `$('.footer .overlay, .footer .wrapper')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [**jQuery.add()**](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .add() method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those
>   elements and the ones passed into the method.

```
var overlayAndContainer = overlay.add(container);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean you want a selection that contains both `.footer .overlay` and `.footer .wrapper`. There are various ways of doing this:

```
$('.footer .overlay').add('.footer .wrapper')
$('.footer').find('.overlay, .wrapper');
$('.footer .overlay, .footer .wrapper');    // probably the best
```

Comment: Why is the last selector the best? I would've guessed the second one.

Comment: @Adam Because it can be passed directly to `document.querySelectorAll`, so the browser's native code (which is much faster than jQuery) can do all the work.

Comment: Very good point. My thinking was for pre-`document.querySelectorAll` times.

Answer (score 1):

```
var all =  $('.footer').find('.overlay, .wrapper')
```

or if you want to reuse the variables

```
var all =  overlay.add(container)
```